# Following along with the Heroku docs to create a MEAN stack app and I am stuck

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, curl, heroku

I am following along with this doc here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api

And I am stuck on the test curl that is supposed to create a new "contact" in the Mongo database.

Up until that point I have followed the directions to the letter. The only difference is that I cloned an existing Heroku app locally instead of creating one in the CLI. I don't think this is causing an error. I cloned the blank app, installed node and dependencies using npm, then created the server.js file exactly like they said and pushed everything to my app.

It seemed successful, I can see in my Heroku account that my previously blank app is now a node app, and I can visit my attached Mongo database. However, I don't see any collections in my database, and this test curl fails:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"firstName":"Chris", "lastName": "Chang", "email": "support@mlab.com"}' http://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/contacts
```

The contact is not posted to the database like it should be. I get a really weird response, the HTML for an application error shows up in my command prompt window, like I visited the wrong page in my app. I don't get any sort of error from express.

I am completely new when it comes to anything MEAN stack and Heroku. I did some courses in code school for node and express, but that's it. Anyone have this type of error when trying to set up MEAN on Heroku? The code that server.js should include is in the article I linked.

### Edit

I figures this one out. I didn't have anything in my routes.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself. My routes weren't set up correctly. Watch those routes!

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly was wrong with the routes? I have a similar issue except I followed the tutorial to the letter, but it still won't let me post anything with the curl command